# Make table cell the same width as its container

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make the table cells (td) the same width as the table. Also eliminate the black space in between each cells.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: white; font-size: 19px; text-align:left;height:378px;color:#6D6E71;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">

<table style="margin:0px;font-size: 16px;width:100%;padding:0px; color:black;">
     <tr  >
     <td style="background:blue; padding:15px 20px;width:100%">First agenda</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td style="background:red;padding:15px 20px;width:100%;">second agenda</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td style="background:yellow;padding:15px 20px;width:100%;">thrid agenda</td>
      </tr>                  
</table>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like :
[image]

I need to make each table cell fill the black areas. I have already eliminated the container's paddings.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z8ygsmv4/ Add border-collapse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Comment: @nevermind Thank you very much! Border-collapse does the job.

Comment: I'll just take a moment to point out that, semantically and in its perhaps simplified form, this looks more like a list than a table.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the suggestion. You are absolutely right this looks more like a list. I just used this as an example. There'll be more details added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
td {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

table {
  background-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 16px;
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
     <tr  >
     <td style="background:blue">First agenda</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td style="background:red">second agenda</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td style="background:yellow">third agenda</td>
      </tr>                  
</table>
```

This is an example of using `border-collapse: collapse` to remove the borders.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is set `cellspacing="0"` and `cellpadding="0"`and style `border:none !important;` to the `<table>` as following :

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: white; font-size: 19px; text-align:left;height:378px;color:#6D6E71;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0px;font-size: 16px;width:100%;padding:0px; color:black;border:none !important;">
     <tr >
     <td style="background:blue; padding:15px 20px;width:100%">First agenda</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td style="background:red;padding:15px 20px;width:100%;">second agenda</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td style="background:yellow;padding:15px 20px;width:100%;">thrid agenda</td>
      </tr>                  
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest that you keep the styling in a seperate stylesheet for tidiness, I hope this helped ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help!